# Is an aircraft capable of flying at 900 km/h at 8000 metres above ground?

Tags: aircraft-performance

There was a question in my maths textbook and I wondered if it was actually possible.

P.S. 8,000 metres is about 26,000 feet.

Comment: Yes, it's normal.  What is your doubt?

Comment: And there are aircraft that can go faster at much lower altitudes. 900 kmh is only about 560mph.

Comment: Is "above the ground" a trap? If you fly at 8 km above Everest you are already at an altitude of 17 km. I wonder what is the reason to have such question in a maths textbook. It can't be answered correctly without knowing a bit of aerodynamics, the difference between groundspeed and airspeed, the characteristics of the standard atmosphere, etc, and I don't see the mathematics interest.

Comment: Likely the math question was not whether the aircraft was capable of flying 900 km/h at 8000 ft, but rather this info was given as context. E.g.: an aircraft flies straight and level at 900 km/h at 8 km above the surface; what is the maximum angular speed of the aircraft as seen from a radar which is placed 50 km off the aircraft's track?

Comment: High level and fast, I submit the SR-71.  Low level and fast, I submit the B1-B.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible, but it is quite fast.

900 km/h is 486 knots.

Assuming no wind and a standard atmosphere, 486 knots ground speed is 486 knots true airspeed (TAS), which is equivalent to a calibrated airspeed (CAS) of 334 knots at 8000 meters.

At that altitude, the maximum operating speed (V<sub>mo</sub>) is usually the limiting factor; if you are a kilometre higher then the maximum operating mach number (M<sub>mo</sub>) will typically become limiting.

334 is above the V<sub>mo</sub> of some airliners (they will need a little bit of tailwind to achieve 900 km/h over ground at 8000 meters), but many are capable of achieving it without wind.

Some examples of V<sub>mo</sub>:

- Boeing 737: 340 kts (350 kts for the Original's)
- Airbus A320 family: 350 kts
- Boeing 747: 365 kts
- Boeing 777: 330 kts
- Airbus A330: 330 kts
- Airbus A340: 330 kts

Comment: @mins I am quite sure the OP doesn't really care about the difference between height and altitude. Nor did he specify the elevation of the terrain or the atmospheric conditions. So assuming ground is at sea level and atmosphere is standard does not seem unreasonable here.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about airliners but aircraft.  There are many aircraft capable of 334 (and a lot faster) at 8000.

Comment: @mins The OP doesn't state that **this** question was asked in their maths textbook. They stated ***a*** question was asked in their math book, which may be a different question. It may not even be related at all to the question posed here, although there likely is a relation otherwise it doesn't make sense to mention the math textbook. Anyway, it doesn't really matter to the answer of the question how the question came about.

Comment: @DeltaLima gets the Pendant O' The Day™ award!

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you for the award, although I am not sure why. Is it for hanging around here? Or did you mean *pedant*? In that case I am honoured to beat mins at that category. I'll get my coat...

Comment: @ymb1, I only see now that you changed classic to originals. Thanks for that, the text was meant to read that originally (no pun intended :-)

Comment: @DeltaLima - you know, it's Friday, I'll give you one of each!

Answer (score 2):

Sure can. Military fighters can exceed 800 KIAS at sea level in full power. Depending upon the aircraft in question, 900 km/h is not an unreasonable speed for a high performance aircraft to fly at while straight and level at that altitude.